# How can I do color text hyperlink in Telerik ASP.NET Core Grid?

Tags: asp.net-core, telerik-grid

How can I do color text hyperlink in Telerik ASP.NET Core Grid?

I don't find description for this in official Telerik forum.
The screenshot is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GSrI.png)

Comment: Share your scenario, not clear what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Coloring the text hyperlink can be achieved using `style` or `css`. When using Telerik for ASP.NET Core, you can use helper `.HtmlAttributes()`. Check out the sample code below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false) 
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Item1).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "color: green;" });
    })
)
```

Comment: Hello Ahmadi Rayyan, You wrote about text color. And how about color hyperlink in Telerik ASP.NET Core Grid?

Comment: @VasilyZaytsev Have you tried it? Is in your column consist of both hyperlink and text?

Comment: I didn't try it. In my column only hyperlink. I need color hyperlinks. For example some red hyperlinks and some yellow hyperlinks.